# Join in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

is it possible to achieve the below mentioned output from table 1 and table 2 
i have tried all the joins like outer join,left join,right join but the required output is not achieved [image: output].please help me . thanks

Comment: you can use `Union`

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Have you tried anything? Please post your code. Also, please edit your question to show data as formatted text, not images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily achieved using a [partition outer join](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=312):

```
WITH table1 AS (SELECT 2014 yr, 'Main' division, 2000 amt FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 2015 yr, 'Main' division, 6000 amt FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 2016 yr, 'Main' division, 7000 amt FROM dual),
     table2 AS (SELECT 2014 yr, 'Center' division, 100 amt FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 2015 yr, 'Center' division, 200 amt FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 2016 yr, 'Center' division, 350 amt FROM dual),
-- end of mimicking your tables; you wouldn't need the above
-- as you already have the tables.
-- You will need the following subquery to define the years you're querying
-- against, though. You can define this either in the WITH clause
-- or as an inline view in the main SQL below
      years AS (SELECT 2014 yr FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 2015 yr FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 2016 yr FROM dual UNION ALL
                SELECT 2017 yr FROM dual)
SELECT yrs.yr,
       t.division,
       NVL(t.amt, 0) amt
FROM   years yrs
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT yr, division, amt FROM table1
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT yr, division, amt FROM table2) t PARTITION BY (t.division)
          ON yrs.yr = t.yr
ORDER BY t.division, yrs.yr;

        YR DIVISION        AMT
---------- -------- ----------
      2014 Center          100
      2015 Center          200
      2016 Center          350
      2017 Center            0
      2014 Main           2000
      2015 Main           6000
      2016 Main           7000
      2017 Main              0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to perform a join and fill in values that do not exist for particular combinations of values, outer joins with UNIONs are a little old fashioned in Oracle.

The more recent method is the "Partitioned outer join".

There is a good write up on them in the "SQL for Reporting and Analysis" guide: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25555/tdpdw_sql.htm#TDPDW0072

Have a review of that, and if you can't work out the correct syntax then maybe ask a new question focussed on the use of partitioned outer joins.

Answer (score 0):

I don't like the query but I think it will give your result. If you had provided test data as inserts I would test it.

```
with years as (select year from select year from table1 union select year from table2), 
     divisions as (select division from select division from table1 union select division from table2)
select y.year, d.division, nvl(t1.amd, 0) 
  from years y cross join divisions d 
  left outer join table1 t1 on (y.year = t1.year and d.division = t1.division) 
union all
select y.year, d.division, nvl(t2.amd, 0) 
  from years y cross join divisions d 
  left outer join table2 t2 on (y.year = t2.year and d.division = t2.division);
```

Comment: `y inner join d on (1=1)` is called a CROSS JOIN and it has its own syntax, which is better to use for clarity: `y cross join d`. Also, the left outer join is distributive over union all; you can do `d cross join y cross join <the result of union all>`

Comment: @mathguy Thanks, yes ther should be `cross join` messy habits. 
I know I can join with union. This I did just for clarity. But maybe it is more clear only for me ;)

Comment: ... and of course I have a typo in the comment (which I can't edit) - at the end it should be `y cross join d LEFT OUTER join < ... >` {:-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNION` and `LEFT OUTER JOIN` like this:

```
SELECT * FROM(
SELECT 
  DISTINCT
  YEARS.YEAR,
  NVL(T1.DIVISION, (SELECT MAX(DIVISION) FROM TABLE1 WHERE DIVISION IS NOT NULL)) DIVISION,
  NVL(T1.AMT, 0)
FROM
(
  SELECT YEAR, DIVISION  FROM TABLE1
  UNION 
  SELECT YEAR, DIVISION FROM TABLE2
) YEARS
LEFT JOIN TABLE1 T1
ON YEARS.YEAR = T1.YEAR
) TAB1
UNION ALL
(
  SELECT 
    DISTINCT
    YEARS.YEAR,
    NVL(T2.DIVISION, (SELECT MAX(DIVISION) FROM TABLE2 WHERE DIVISION IS NOT NULL)) DIVISION,
    NVL(T2.AMT, 0)
  FROM
  (
    SELECT YEAR, DIVISION  FROM TABLE1
    UNION 
    SELECT YEAR, DIVISION FROM TABLE2
  ) YEARS
  LEFT JOIN TABLE2 T2
  ON YEARS.YEAR = T2.YEAR
)
ORDER BY 2 DESC, 1;
```